# How to configure plugin verifier as it runs during JetBrains Marketplace admission?

Tags: jetbrains-ide

Can you advise how to configure the plugin verifier so it would return errors as JetBrains marketplace does, please?

Error from the marketplace:

```
[plugin] depends on plugin com.jetbrains.php that couldn't be resolved with respect to IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate IU-202.8194.7 (2020.2.4)
Note that the [plugin] cannot be installed into IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate IU-202.8194.7 (2020.2.4) without mandatory com.jetbrains.php
Found 1 incompatibility with IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate IU-202.8194.7 (2020.2.4), some of which may be caused by the missing dependencies.
```

When running runPluginVerifier locally everything is fine:

```
2020-12-11T13:01:29 [main] INFO  verification - Finished 1 of 2 verifications (in 3.1 s): IU-202.8194.7 against com.lokalise.jetbrainsideplugin:1.0.0-alpha: Compatible
2020-12-11T13:01:30 [main] INFO  verification - Finished 2 of 2 verifications (in 3.6 s): PS-202.6948.87 against com.lokalise.jetbrainsideplugin:1.0.0-alpha: Compatible
```

I would like to catch such an error during CI at most instead of throwing the plugin at the marketplace team.

Here is the gradle task configuration (Kotlin):

```
import org.jetbrains.intellij.tasks.RunPluginVerifierTask
...
tasks.runPluginVerifier {
    ideVersions("PS-202.6948.87,IU-202.8194.7")
    setFailureLevel(RunPluginVerifierTask.FailureLevel.ALL)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with it quite a bit. Found it.

```
tasks {
    runPluginVerifier {
        ideVersions.set(listOf("PS-202.6948.87","IU-202.8194.7"))
    }
    ...
}
```